# LibGDX test rectangles for collision

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to draw rectangles on my Java 2D game to represent the invisible rectangles used as bounds for my sprites.

This code is in my `render()` method in the `PlayState` class, and for some reason it erases all the Textures I have painted to the screen. 
Shape in the code below is an object of the ShapeRenderer class.

```
shape.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
shape.setColor(1, 1, 0, 1);
shape.rect(bird.getLeftBird().getPosLeftBird().x,
    bird.getLeftBird().getPosLeftBird().y, 35, 40);
shape.end();
```

Is there way to use the `BatchSprite draw()` method to draw rectangles?

I'm using the `BadLogic` math utility class.

Here is my render() method:

```
@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    sb.begin();
    sb.draw(bg, cam.position.x - (cam.viewportWidth / 2), cam.position.y- (cam.viewportHeight/2));
    sb.draw(diamond.getTexture(), diamond.getPosition().x, diamond.getPosition().y);

    for (int i = 0; i < birds.size; i++) {
        Bird bird = birds.get(i);
        if (bird.getId() == 0) {
//                shape.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
//                shape.setColor(1, 1, 0, 1);
//                shape.rect(bird.getLeftBird().getPosLeftBird().x,
//                        bird.getLeftBird().getPosLeftBird().y, 35, 40);
//                shape.end();
            sb.draw(bird.getLeftBird().getLeftBird(), bird.getLeftBird().getPosLeftBird().x, bird.getLeftBird().getPosLeftBird().y);
        } else {
            sb.draw(bird.getRightBird().getRightBird(), bird.getRightBird().getPosRightBird().x, bird.getRightBird().getPosRightBird().y);
        }
    }
    sb.end();
}
```

Comment: Show your whole render method. Something's wrong if your sprites are not showing up just because of the shape renderer.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I added the render method. thanks.

Comment: You're probably messing stuff up by trying to render with shape renderer in between calls to spriteBatch's begin and end. Also, you should be calling Gdx.gl.glClear in the render method before drawing anything.

Comment: ah man, thanks for the catch. I knew that, just didn't notice I took it out at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a `ShapeRenderer` instead of the `BatchSprite`. I don't think it's possible to draw rectangles with `BatchSprite`. Try something like this (in your render method):

```
public void render() {
    // Rest of your code
    // ...
    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
    shapeRenderer.rect(xpos, ypos, width, height);
    shapeRenderer.end();
}
```

Comment: sorry, I added a little more text. I used `ShapeRender` and that was what made all my other objects disappeared. I edited to explain that better and showed my render class.